# How to avoid CTE in query?

Tags: sql-server

I prepared a sample table, to demonstrate what I want to acheive.

```
drop table #Temp
create table #Temp
(
    col1 nvarchar(50),
    col2 nvarchar(50),
    col3 nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #temp (col1,col2,col3) values (null, null, 'W')
```

How to avoid this cte and have the same result?

```
with cte as (
select COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) as result from #temp
)
select * from cte where result is not null
```

Comment: What is the rationale to avoid using a CTE?

Comment: The problem that you're having is that your "where" clause depends on the computed column? Well you could still write your "where" clause in terms of the coalesce, or "(col1 is not null or col2 is not null or col3 is not null)", etc.

Comment: There is not rationale, I just wanted to know if there is any other way. I tried to do it myself but I could not do that.

Comment: `WITH ... AS (..)` is more or less defined  in the ANSI/ISO SQL standards. as a SQL "preprocessor" statement, to reuse queries more easy.   So most likely your RDSM would optimize your CTE and run your SQL query as `select COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) as result from #Temp WHERE COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) IS NOT NULL` instead when the optimizer notices that CTE to be redundant

Comment: To back up mine last comment.. MySQL the RDMS which i know best allowes checking this internal SQL rewrite ... See this [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/btaa3G4eD5QChFm38km35e/1), notice the SQL queries outputs they are the same, what you see are the internal SQL processed SQL..  I am not sure if something like this exists in SQL Server..

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e6cc/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Temp
(
    col1 nvarchar(50),
    col2 nvarchar(50),
    col3 nvarchar(50)
)
insert into temp (col1,col2,col3) values (null, null, 'W')
insert into temp (col1,col2,col3) values (null, null, null)
insert into temp (col1,col2,col3) values ('A', 'B', 'W')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from temp
where COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) IS NOT NULL
```

**Query 2**:

```
select CASE WHEN  COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) IS NULL THEN 'Undefined' ELSE
COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) END from temp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e6cc/4/0)**:

```
|   col1 |   col2 | col3 |
|--------|--------|------|
| (null) | (null) |    W |
|      A |      B |    W |
```

Answer (score 1):

For your query, it is equivalent as following 2 query

```
select  COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) as result
from    #Temp
where   COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) is not null
```

or

```
select  * 
from 
(
    select COALESCE(col1,col2,col3) as result from #Temp
) as D
where   result is not null
```